# Selenium 4 can't find the element

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, webdriverwait

I'm creating rambler autoreg mail using selenium python and encountered a problem that selenium `can't find the item` by xpath on the page, although it is there. It's clear from the error that selenium just can't find the item (error text at the very bottom). Been looking for a solution, but they are mostly all related to another problem, please help you, thanks in advance.

**HTML**

```
...
<footer class = "styles_popupFooter__1pUND" ...>
    <div class="styles_footer__wCsAz rui-Typography-reset rui-Typography-text">
        <a class="styles_link___lR7s styles_link__lCdad" ... >Registration<a>
        ...
    <div>
    ...
<footer>
    ...
```

**Python**

```
# Selenium 4
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

class GenerateEmail:
    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver
        self.wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)

    def main(self):
        url = "https://mail.rambler.ru/?utm_source=head&utm_campaign=self_promo&utm_medium=header&utm_content=mail"
        self.driver.get(url)

        value = '//div[@class="styles_footer__wCsAz rui-Typography-reset rui-Typography-text"]//a[text()="Registration"]'
        self.wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, value)))
        button = self.driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=value)
        button.click()

def start():
    try:
        s = Service(executable_path='driver/geckodriver.exe')
        driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=s)

        g_email = GenerateEmail(driver)
        g_email.main()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        driver.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start()
```

**Error**

```
Message:
Stacktrace:
WebDriverError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.jsm:186:5
NoSuchElementError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.jsm:398:5
element.find/</<@chrome://remote/content/marionette/element.js:300:16
```

Answer (score 0):

The element `Registration` you are after is inside an `iframe` you need switch it first in order to access the element. Use `Webdriverwait()` and `frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it()`

```
  def main(self):
        url = "https://mail.rambler.ru/?utm_source=head&utm_campaign=self_promo&utm_medium=header&utm_content=mail"
        self.driver.get(url)
        
        self.wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "//div[@data-id-frame='embed']//iframe")))

        value = '//div[@class="styles_footer__wCsAz rui-Typography-reset rui-Typography-text"]//a[text()="Registration"]'
        self.wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, value)))
        button = self.driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=value)
        button.click()
```